# Device choosing weaker signal strength WiFi endpoint in Synology mesh network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I own the **Synology RT2600ac** router. I added the **Synology MR2200ac** to deal with some weak signal issues in the opposite corner of the house upstairs. Unfortunately my **Peloton** Bike (an Android device), which only 6 to 10 feet away from the **RT2600ac**, is always connecting to the **MR2200ac** despite the signal being so poor that we cannot stream classes. I have to reboot the **MR2200ac** so the **Peloton** is forced to join the network using the **RT2600ac** endpoint.

Does anyone know the protocol for a device to connect to a mesh endpoint and why in the protocol would a device choose an endpoint that has a weaker connection?

While this first manifested in the Peloton it occurs in other devices as well. Take for instance this Roku TV labeled "Basement TV". It is literally 3 ft away from the **RT2600ac** but instead it is connected to the MR2200ac that is upstairs with only limited strength connection.

[image: Basement TV connected to the 5Ghz MR2200ac endpoint]

**Edited for further clarity.**

Comment: Commonly different band (5 GHz and 2.4 GHz) . Your bike may be choosing the 2.4 GHz band.  Also the bike NIC may need a new driver.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: My guess is that the bike's trying to connect to the 2500 first because that's where it first learned about the network. I'd force it to forget the network and reconnect so that it sees it as a new network; maybe even power off the router at that time so that it has no other choice but to connect to the 2200.